# Responsive search bar

Tags: html, css, responsive

[image: what happens]

At `max-width: 380px;` the text should disappear and only the search icon should appear. However, the text doesn't disappear.

```css
@media screen and(max-width: 380px) {
  nav div form span .text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="search-container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" />
    <button type="submit">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span>
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a space between span and .text which should not be there as they are trying to select the same element. A space indicates a descendant.

Comment: Also, add a space between `and` and `(max-width: 380px)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @AHaworth said in the comments, spaces select siblings, whether direct or not. So if you have a span inside a div, or a span inside a p inside a div, `div span` would select that. That's not what you want. You want `span.text`. That selects `span`s with class `text`.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  span.text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/6ba8be0f46.js"></script>
```

[**JSFiddle -- Resize the window here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/7sur92xd/1/)

Comment: @A Hawroth @Someone_who_likes_SE I want to decrease the width of the search bar as I go down to 320px such that the search bar and search button always lie side by side.

Comment: @AbhranilDas If you have another question, then please ask it as another question.

Comment: @AbhranilDas It might not be possible, because different devices have different fonts/font sizes and it might not be possible to know the width of each one. I'll try. But if you want to, you can use [`display:table;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display-internal) on something that has width 100% to force the two to take up 100% space.